# php search module

Tags: php, mysql, search, content-management-system

I need your help in creating a search result page for my site. Its a simple php cms site simply fetching content from mysql.
Using a simple query to fetch search

```
$search = $_GET["search"];
$search = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['search']);

$searchresult = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pgcontent LIKE '%$search%'");   

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchresult)) 
    {
        echo '<h3>' . $row["PageTitle"] . '</h1>';
        echo '<p>' . $row["PageContent"] . '</p><br /><br />';  
    }
```

What i want to do is not to display the whole page content, just the line where any word matches with the search term ... or just the first few lines of that page where the search term was found.

Friends can you help me in doing this please? it will be a big favor ... thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Your code is massively open to SQL injections.

Comment: Just to clarify: your query returns multi-line strings, and you want to pick a line from that string that matches. Sounds like a job for a `grep` like command...

Comment: Why do you have `searchresult` and `searchcontent` ? which one is right?

Comment: Just letting you know, a hacker could destroy your service by searching for "' DROP TABLE pages #" (without the quotes).

Comment: @Samuel Cook, friend can you tell me what can i do to secure code from SQL injections ?

Comment: War10ck covered it all in his comment. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements. It's not that hard to switch over. In fact, just unlearn everything you know about mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run post processing on `$row["PageContent"]`

Something like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchresult)) 
{
    echo '<h3>' . $row["PageTitle"] . '</h3>';

    $position = strpos($row["PageContent"], $search);
    $snippet = substr($row["PageContent"], $position - 100, $position + 100);

    echo '<p>' . $snippet . '</p>';
    echo '<br /><br />';  
}
```

Where you begin your snippet 100 characters from the beginning of the matched term and end it 100 characters after the beginning of the term. Obviously you tune this to whatever you want but this is the basic idea.

If I missed the point let me know and I may update.

Comment: No problem. You can also use the variations of strpos (strrpos for last occurrence, etc) to chop the string up by something like beginning of a sentence, whole words, and so on so you don't end up with strange sentence fragments. ...mething to write abo... see what I mean? You should play with strpos and if you get stuck, post a new question on SO about how to make sure your snippet is trimmed to a human readable sentence.